# How to keep track of users download(s) in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I use Laravel 4.

I have a download button in my view.

I have a lot of `users` that have the access to `see/click` to download from that button.

Here is my question,

is there any way to keep track of `how many` time my file has been downloaded and by `whom` ?

Let’s say,

- user A download 27 times
- user B download 5 times
- user C never download at all
- user D download 200 time

so on and so forth …

My Controller Function

```
public function file_download($id)
    {

        $catalog_download = CatalogDownload::findOrFail($id);
        $distributor      = Auth::user()->distributor()->first();
        $export_type      = $distributor->export_type()->first();
        $product_export =  $catalog_download->product_exports()->first();

        $destinationPath  = base_path().'/app/files/product_export/'. $catalog_download->id.'/'. $export_type->id.'/';
        $file_name        = $product_export->file_path;
        $pathToFile       = $destinationPath .$file_name;

        return Response::download($pathToFile);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your database

You should create another attribute. Let’s called it `download_count`

- integer
- Set default to 0

In your controller function, at the end, just do.

- $user->download_count = $user->download_count +1;
- $user->save();

Every-time,the user trying to download sth, they will need to go through that function - right ?

Just `increment`(+1) it, every-time, they go through it. I hope I am clear enough. Good Luck :)

Comment: I like your solution. Well Answer ! I have to try it, and I will let you know.

Comment: Ohh... my pleasure. please let me know, if my solution work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an ajax call with the username and the downloadfile's name as the Ajax call 's data to the button and safe every click on the button to the DB. Then you can simply query for the file and user combination and you will get the number of downloads.

Other way would be to add the save function to your controller and save above mentioned combination through the controller

Comment: Can you give me a quick sample code of Ajax call ? when you can - :) Don't have to be correct syntax, pseudocode is fine. I just need to see the basic logics - if I decide to do this in Ajax. Thanks. I hope you can do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

The only option I can think of is to store it in the database.

Once the user clicks the download button, add +1 in the database.